# Click events not working in cloned buttons within fixed columns

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

After following https://stackoverflow.com/a/62034229/4217097 to make fixedColumns work in Angular Datatables, I found that the buttons inside the fixed column no longer fire the (click) event. The fixed columns are okay though.

angular.json

```
  "styles": [
         "src/styles.scss",
         "node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css",
         "node_modules/datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
         "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
         "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
         "node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js",
         "node_modules/datatables.net-fixedcolumns/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"
  ]
```

component.ts

```
   import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';
   import 'datatables.net-fixedcolumns';

   ...

   this.dtOptionsTasklist = {
       fixedColumns:  {
          leftColumns: 1,
          rightColumns: 1
       }
   }
```

If you've solved this before, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, for anyone googling in the future, just use `position:sticky;` if you only need to support modern browsers. Check the solutions here: [Table with fixed header and fixed column on pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811653/table-with-fixed-header-and-fixed-column-on-pure-css)